# Drupal Views: Join file_managed with custom table

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a custom table with a file id that I want to join with the file_managed table.
My query looks like this:

```
SELECT ofertias_producto.sku AS sku
FROM 
{ofertias_producto} ofertias_producto
INNER JOIN {file_managed} file_managed_ofertias_producto 
ON ofertias_producto.id_imagen = file_managed_ofertias_producto.fid
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

The join is done right. The problem is that I'm not seeing any fields of the file managed table.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You did not **SELECT** any field from **file_managed** table

```
SELECT ofertias_producto.sku AS sku, file_managed_ofertias_producto.some_field as some_field
FROM 
{ofertias_producto} ofertias_producto
INNER JOIN {file_managed} file_managed_ofertias_producto 
ON ofertias_producto.id_imagen = file_managed_ofertias_producto.fid
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Change some_field with appropriate field name of file managed table

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer... The field list in the view was not showing any field from the file managed table... it was an error... To fix it I had to update modules like entity, views and ctools, then it worked as expected. Seems like old modules had a few bugs, I don't know exactly which of them was wrong.

Comment: glad to hear that you fixed it by updating module